# Carrierwave direct gem installation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, carrierwave-direct

I have an uploader for my rails project called `BulkImagesUploader` that takes in a zip file and uploads it to S3 using `carrierwave`. This had been working fine but I find myself having to upload the files directly from browser to S3 using `carrierwave_direct` gem.

I have followed the instructions on the gems README, however I'm getting an error saying

```
/home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/fog-0.7.2/lib/fog/core/provider.rb:5:in `extended': undefined method `providers' for Fog:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Below is my code

Gemfile

```
# Gemfile.rb

source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '>= 2.4.1'

gem 'aasm', '~> 4.12'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 6.0'
gem 'acts_as_commentable'
gem 'ancestry'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
gem 'cancancan'
gem 'carrierwave_direct'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.0'
gem 'client_side_validations'
gem 'client_side_validations-simple_form'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'devise'
gem 'dotenv-rails'
gem 'fog'
# gem 'fog-aws'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'mini_magick', '>=  4.9.2'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'paranoia', '~> 2.2'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
gem 'ransack'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'wicked', '>= 1.3.3'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw]
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'rails-erd'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.7'
  gem "switch_user"
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem "awesome_print", '~> 1.8.0', require: "ap"
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15', '< 4.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'shoulda'
end
gem 'rubocop', require: false
# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: %i[mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby]
```

Initializer

```
# config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider: 'AWS',
    aws_access_key_id: ENV['AWS_KEY'],
    aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET'],
    region: ENV['AWS_REGION']
  }
  config.fog_directory = ENV['S3_BUCKET']
end
```

Uploader

```
class BulkImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader
  def extension_whitelist
    %w(zip)
  end
end
```

Stack Trace

```
/home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/fog-0.7.2/lib/fog/core/provider.rb:5:in `extended': undefined method `providers' for Fog:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/fog-aws-3.3.0/lib/fog/aws.rb:9:in `extend'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/fog-aws-3.3.0/lib/fog/aws.rb:9:in `<module:AWS>'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/fog-aws-3.3.0/lib/fog/aws.rb:8:in `<module:Fog>'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/fog-aws-3.3.0/lib/fog/aws.rb:7:in `<main>'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/carrierwave_direct-2.0.0/lib/carrierwave_direct.rb:4:in `<main>'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
    from /home/moiz/Desktop/Projects/ca-bfl/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `block in perform'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
    from /home/moiz/Desktop/Projects/ca-bfl/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    from /home/moiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/moiz/Desktop/Projects/ca-bfl/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    from /home/moiz/Desktop/Projects/ca-bfl/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

What could be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised the error was with the version of fog that rails was using. The version it was supposed to use was fog 2.0 but the `Gemfile.lock` mentioned fog 0.7.

If anyone else comes across this error check the version of your gems. That is most likely the cause of your error